# Why do people use slime blocks and honey blocks in the same redstone machine?

Tags: minecraft-redstone

Some larger flying machines I've seen have alternating rows of honey and slime blocks. Is there some important difference or interaction between the two that would require both types to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slime blocks will pull other slime blocks but will not pull honey blocks. Honey blocks will pull other honey blocks but not slime block. This means if you have a design that needs several honey blocks or slime blocks positioned so that they would touch each other without moving each other you will have to alternate between the two.

Comment: I figured this was probably the case.

Comment: I can accept an answer in 6 minutes.